# ¿Cómo puedo cambiar el atributo "list" de un input con javascript?

Tags: javascript, atributos, javascript-metodo

Tengo un `input` que muestra los elementos de una `datalist`, inicialmente muestra los elementos de la `datalist` de `id="list_one"`, quiero que al marcar el `checkbox` cambie la lista que debe mostrar a la que tiene `id="list_two"`.

CÓDIGO HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="CheckListTwo" onclick="SelectList();">                                        

<input type="text" id="loanTo" list="list_one" name="one"> //Input que muestra los elementos de la lista

<datalist id="list_one">  
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
</datalist>

<datalist id="list_two">  
   <option value="A">A</option>
   <option value="B">B</option>
   <option value="C">C</option>
</datalist>
```

CÓDIGO JAVASCRIPT:

```
function SelectList(){
    var checker = document.getElementById("CheckListTwo");    
    var campo = document.getElementById("loanTo");
                                        
    if(checker.checked){        
        campo.list = "list_two";
        campo.name = "two";  
                                  
        }else{
        campo.setAtribut = "list_one";
        campo.name = "one";                                           
        }
}
```

La función modifica el atributo `name` pero no el atributo `list`.

Answer (score 0):

Supongo que no estás usando un editor de código porque tienes `setAtribut` en lugar de `setAttribute`, así que empieza por descargar uno para que te avise de esos errores.

Puedes usar `setAttribute` para ambos casos:

```
if (checker.checked) {
    campo.setAttribute("list", "list_two");
    campo.setAttribute("name", "two");
} else {
    campo.setAttribute("list", "list_one");
    campo.setAttribute("name", "one");
}
```

Documentación:

[Element.setAttribute](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/setAttribute)